# convert from 2D point on a plane to 3D

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

Given a 2D point that is on the surface of a triangle, where each corner of the triangle is a 3D point, how can you compute the corresponding 3D point of the 2D point?

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited for: http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mjgpy3 no, this is far too basic math.

Comment: What is the 2D orientation on the triangle (assuming the location of the point is in reference to the triangle)? I.e., where are the x- and y-axes, and which way is positive?

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I have three 3D points for the plane; I think its normal to turn them into a single point and a normal.  Two of the points represent start and stop for a journey; I want to convert the 3D points to 2D, plot a path in 2D, then convert the 2D path back to 3D.

Comment: @Will you may be confusing [math.se] (which is "for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields") with the place sometimes incorrectly by SO users for math questions, [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net), which is indeed for "research level math questions". This question would be welcome on [math.se].

Answer (score 5):

To get the 3D location of a particular 2D point on a triangle, use barycentric coordinates to interpolate the locations of the 3D vertices:

```
2D coordinates:  u,v such that 0 <= u,v <= 1  and  u+v <= 1
  ->  barycentric coordinates:  add t such that  t+u+v = 1  ->  t = 1-(u+v)

3D vertices:  V1, V2, and V3
  ->  result = u*V1 + v*V2 + t*V3
```